# How do I get my question cross-posted to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

How do I get my question cross-posted to Stack Overflow?

It has not been answered and I am in need of an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Flag the question for moderator attention and have them migrate it over. [Just like you were already told](https://superuser.com/questions/360006/making-qemu-based-marss-simulation-deterministic) a month ago.

It's *either* here *or* there. There is no cross-posting functionality, and if you post the same question on multiple sites yourself you'll only annoy other users and find your question(s) closed.

---

By the way, if you're asking about [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/371343/suse-linux-getting-a-static-ip), it will likely be closed as off-topic on SO.